# Java regex: split comma-separated values but ignore commas in quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have text as follows:

```
"text","1","more, more text","3"
```

Could anyone kindly show me what regex delimeters I have to use to get the following:

```
text
1
more, more text
3
```

I was reading the Sun tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), up until "Methods of the matcher class" but I am still at a loss. Thanks!

If it were something like `text,1,more` it would be easy enough, but unfortunately it's not like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either go straight for the split() method like this:

```
    String text = "\"text\",\"1\",\"more, more text\",\"3\"";

    String[] split = text.split("\"(,\")?");
    for (String string : split) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

(beware that this returns a length 5 array, with the first position being an empty string)

Or, if you want to use a Pattern/Matcher, you can do it like this:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Excellent. I will parse the text to remove the first quote (to deal with the empty string) and use your regex. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this pattern: `"(.+?)"`

It will match 1 or more characters between double quotes. The part of the text between the quotes is available as `matcher.group(1)`.

Look at the javadoc for `Pattern` class to learn more. Also, look at `matcher.find()` method.

Comment: +1 I have been looking for that pattern for quite a while (matching one or more characters). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could try this `[^\"]+(?<!\",?)`

Answer (score 0):

You could get every part that start with an `"` and finish with another `"` and then substring the first and last character of each part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that. I know, it is not good solution, but it can help you :)

```
string[] s=text.split("\",\""); 
s[0]=s[0].substring(1);
s[s.length-1]=s[s.length-1].substring(0,s[s.length-1].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"[^"]*"
```

seems it is! 
in java string you can use

```
"\"[^\"]*\""
```

You can test it online here: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Comment: it works on the website , but when I try it in java it returns an empty string and four commas. Really nice website bdw! :)

Comment: It finds any number of non-quota symbols between quotas. That is it works right with empty strings ("","qwert,tyy"," ")

Comment: try this code:
 `public static void main(String[] args) {
   String text = "\"text\",\"1\",\"more, more text\",\"3\"";

      String[] split = text.split("\"[^\"]*\"");
      for (String string : split) {
          System.out.println(string);
      }
 }`